# Elegant Way of Converting Unicode Characters to HTML in C#

Tags: c#, html, unicode, html-encode

just wondering if anyone knows of a good way to convert strings with unicode characters into html entities using C#.  For instance, I would like to convert strings in the following way

"This character É" should become "This character &Eacute;"

I am currently doing it manually using regular expressions.  But this is ugly and limited to only characters that I explicitly add to the code. Built in support seems to be limited to basic characters like quotes.

Some goals/constraints:

- Should work for any unicode character that has an html representation
- For cases without a valid html representation I'd like to strip those characters out
- Open to considering a 3rd party library
- We aren't working with massive strings, but looking for reasonable performance.

For context, the end goal is to convert user entered text into a PDF via an html-to-PDF conversion tool.  The HTML (generated using the moustache-sharp templating tool) is sort of an intermediate step that we use to avoid building the PDF manually.  But we have customers from non-English speaking areas who would like to use these special characters, and we've had to manually add characters each time there is a new one that they would like to use.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [HtmlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I think that's exactly what I was looking for.  Seems to at least work on my test set.  Thanks!